# How can I return more than one row from an SQL select statement with average function?

Tags: mysql

I have a table `churchattendance`, with `monthId`, `GroupId`, and each group has a `district`. When I do a `select` statement to get the all the `district` names in that group, it works.

Each of these districts should have an average attendance (`swschildren`, `mbsChildren` etc.) for a particular month, so I'm using the `average` function.

When I tried this in MySQL, I only get one row, instead of all the districts with their average of attendance for the `monthId`. Is there a way I can do that with one SQL statement?

```
SELECT AVG(swsChildren) FROM churchattendance WHERE monthId=1 AND groupId=2
```

Inside the `groupId` of `2`, I have two districts - `districtIds` of `1` and `2`.

Comment: Define what you mean by a "Average function" , also are you using PHP or just MySQL?

Comment: @Innervisions In the domain of relational databases, there exists the concept of functions. One such function is average. If that's difficult to grasp then there's little that can be done.

Comment: I'm using MYSQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to group, as `AVG` is an aggregate function:

```
SELECT groupId, monthId, AVG(swsChildren) FROM churchattendance GROUP BY groupId, monthId
```

Comment: GROUP BY cannot work for me, from my dB here using mysql, when I do a SELECT * FROM churchattendance WHERE groupId =2 AND monthId =1 I get 5 roles, 3 roles of districtId =2 and 2 roles of districtId=3. I want to be able to do average of those 3 and 2 roles separately but together so that I have 2 query results

Comment: @Jerry It would help if you would put all your requirements into the question itself, maybe data sample and expected result. If you want to use `AVG`, then you have to use `GROUP BY`. Eventually you may need to put more columns into the grouping clause, depending on the granularity you want to get. If you want to calculate average for some set of rows, but preserve them in the final result, then you will either self-join or two separate quries and combining their results in the app (if you have one).

Comment: @michaJIS, thanks, it helped. I eventually learnt how to use the AVG function with group by

Comment: Then you may wish to consider accepting my answer https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers @Jerry